# How to trim a extra space in the JCR property value while searching nodes using a AEM Query builder?

Tags: aem

I have a JCR node with a property pageID.  The pageID has a value "123 " in the node.  I'm using the below query to search for a page using the pageID propery.

`queryMap.put("path" , "/content/mysite/pages");
queryMap.put("property" , "pageID");
queryMap.put("property.1_value" , "123");`

While executing this query in AEM I'm not getting any result, since the property value has a extra space ("123 ") in JCR node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if we can ignore this space during search, but can suggest you next query params:

```
path=/content/mysite/pages
property=pageID
property.operation=like
property.value=123_
```

This params for Query Builder equals to next xpath query:

```
/jcr:root/content/mysite/pages//* 
[
jcr:like(@pageID, '123_') 
]
```

`_` stands there for one **any** symbol. So this query will find nodes with property values like *'123 '*, *'123f'* and so on. So this query will not find just *'123'*.

Also, instead of `_` you can use `%` which stands for **zero** or **more** symbols.

In both cases, you should post-process your result (to remove entries like *'123f'*).